# Array for storing objects with different template value

Tags: c++, arrays, class, templates, abstract

I have a class `list` defined as:

```
template <typename T> class list
{
  (...) code
};
```

Then another 2 classes that derive from it:

```
class integer_list : public list<int>
{
  //it has methods specialized for working with integer numbers
};

class char_list: public list<char>
{
  //it has methods specialized for working with strings - a sort of enhanced string class
};
```

My wish is to make a vector of these 2 derived classes combined. I can only think of making a base class with only one pure virtual method. Like this:

```
class base_class
{
  public:
    virtual ~base_class() = 0;
};
```

Therefore, the `list` class should be defined this way:

```
template <typename T> class list : public base_class
{
  (...) code
};
```

Then, declaring an array of `base_class` pointers would let me store addresses of different types of objects, like `integer_list` and `char_list`.

---

The question is: are there any other ways of doing the same thing? Maybe doing it even better?

Comment: Yes, possible, but don't declare destructor as pure virtual, as destructor calling sequence needs to call base class's destructor. Designate some other pure virtual function to declare base_class as abstract.

Comment: You could do this, but you always have to declare a class, which is basically just a dummy-class. Another approach, which is a bit more complex, is a very generic class that can store anything. For example [boost::any](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/any.html) implements this by using a void pointer.

Comment: @DebasishJana: As long as the pure virtual destructor has also a definition, it is ok.

Comment: I see. I'm quite new to boost library. Having what you have said, I think I'll take a look at it's definition (boost::any), if it's not too complex.

Comment: How do you intend for the container to work? To me it seems like you are asking for a container that is a template that can hold multiple types. So it would be a list of ints and a chars? Doing so could be done in a few ways? if you want each element to be both an int and a char grouped together there is a few ways that could be done or if you want each element to be different, say slot 0 is an int and slot 1 is a char that may also be possible. I can't think of a good way to try and answer properly for you without further understanding what you are trying to achieve?